# Necessary condition for a singular matrix pencil

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are both rectangular symmetric real-valued matrices, and $det(A-\lambda B)=0$ for all scalar values of $\lambda$. Does it necessarily follow that $Ax_B = B x_A$ for some pair of vectors $x_A, x_B$, such that $A x_A = 0$ and $B x_B = 0$? If such a pair of vectors exists, it is easy to see that $det(A-\lambda B)=0$, but I'm having trouble showing the converse.

Comment: What does "pencil" mean (in the title)?

Comment: Please see the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_pencil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true in general. Take
$$
A+\lambda B=\pmatrix{1&\lambda&0\\ 0&1&\lambda\\0&0&0}.
$$
Then $Ae_3=0$, $Be_1=0$. But $Ae_1=e_1\ne Be_3=e_2$.

The claim fails because there is no polynomial of degree $1$ such that
$$
(A+\lambda B)x(\lambda)=0
$$
for all $\lambda$. The minimal degree general solution for the example above is
$$
x(\lambda) = e_3 - \lambda e_2 + \lambda^2 e_1.
$$

---

The example can be modified to work with symmetric matrices:
$$
A+\lambda B=\pmatrix{0&0&1&\lambda&0\\ 0&0&0&1&\lambda\\1&0&0&0&0\\ \lambda&1&0&0&0\\0&\lambda&0&0&0}.
$$
The upper-right block has full rank. The parametrized vectors in the null  space are given by
$$
x(\lambda)=e_5 - \lambda e_4 + \lambda^2 e_3.
$$
And $Ae_5=0$, $Be_3=0$, $Ae_3=e_1\ne Be_5=e_2$.

Comment: It seems that your example involves non-symmetric matrices. As mentioned in the original question, we assume that both $A$ and $B$ are symmetric.